# Youtube SeekTo Suddenly stopped working - Looping video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

So from what I can gather one or two things are going from with my youtube video's either the seekTo function has stopped working or the hole API has....(Or youtube has changed something) Now please take in mind my codes were working flawlessly without fault untill yesterday... (code usually doesn't break over night).

Here are 2 sites with the SeekTo function that loops the video via PlayerState ENDED:

http://imvu.url.ph/aattpx/DC_MAR/Base/XML/COMPIC_X1/2014/LayDStroke/maintemp/index.html

http://imvu.url.ph/FTP/2013/System/Core/Int/Warning/Dont_Not_Touch/DKLAY2013BLUE/Layout/Infuriate/index.html

The codes for the youtube video are more or less identical so I'll just post 1 of the codes:

view-source:imvu.url.ph/aattpx/DC_MAR/Base/XML/COMPIC_X1/2014/LayDStroke/maintemp/video.html

```
<div id="youtube-fs"><iframe id="youtube-iframe"   type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/o2cvRsiRkqs?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&controls=0&rel=0&wmode=transparent&vq=hd720&hd=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque" ></iframe>   <script type="text/javascript">


<!--
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
player.quality = 'hd720';
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('youtube-iframe', { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } }); }

function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720'); event.target.playVideo(); }

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

 if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
    event.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
}
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) { player.seekTo(0, true);  } // end if
      }
        -->
    </script>
    </div>
</div></div>
```